# How to locally test my app in production with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I need to know if my app works properly locally when concatenated/minified as I'm using things like ng-annotate and angular-meteor.

In other words, I want to see my app in production as if I deployed it, but locally.

Is there a way without having to use `meteor deploy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command `meteor --production`